# How to compile standalone scala

Tags: scala, compilation

Just starting to learn scala.. I can't seem to figure out how to compile something into a standalone application. I think I almost have a working .jar file, but keep getting a Main-Class error even though it's in the manifest,

Comment: Can you include your manifest in your question, and the location and filename?

Comment: the manifest file (Manifest.mf) contains 'Main-Class: HelloWorld'

it's located in ~/foo, along with HelloWorld.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala programs require at a minimum the `scala-library.jar` file that accompanied the Scala Development Kit whose compiler you used to compile the sources. This is in addition to any 3rd-party Java (or Scala) libraries you might use. So from the perspective of building a stand-alone application (i.e., one that can be launched with a `java -jar ...` command) you must treat the `scala-library.jar` like a 3rd-party library.

Comment: does not including scala-library.jar have anything to do with the Main-Class error?

Comment: Yes, typically it does because the class containing the `main(args: Array[String]): Unit` method cannot be loaded due to failed dependencies on the Scala standard library.